# Iterate through JSON object in php

Tags: php, json

```
   echo $_COOKIE[$cart_cookie]; //prints   "[{\"id\":1353,\"product\":\"prod23\",\"quantity\":1,\"price\":43},{\"id\":133453,\"product\":\"prod\",\"quantity\":1,\"price\":23}]"
   $json_data = json_decode($_COOKIE[$cart_cookie]);
            echo $json_data; // prints [{"id":1353,"product":"prod23","quantity":1,"price":43},{"id":133453,"product":"prod","quantity":1,"price":23}]
            foreach ($json_data as $item) { // Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() 


            }
```

Could anyone suggest, what am I missing while iterating JSON in php ? As I'm getting **Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()** when running this code.

Comment: @Orlangure updated.!!

Comment: Is the cookie double-encoded so $json_data is actually a string?

Comment: @takteek `echo is_string ($json_data);` returns `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON string has a wrong format. It has been quoted and quotes inside it have been escaped, like would have been the effect of `addslashes`.

Your code does not reveal where this tampering happened, but it would be best you would remove the cause of this. If your version of PHP is below 5.4, then please turn the [magic_quots_gpc](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc) configuration off.

But given the current situation, you can fix the string back to valid JSON as follows:

```
$json_data = json_decode(stripslashes(trim($_COOKIE[$cart_cookie],'"')));
```

So, there are two functions applied:

- `trim(..., '"')`: removes the first and last character from the string, i.e. the wrapping double quotes;
- `stripslashes(...)`: un-escapes whatever was escaped inside your string, e.g. the double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like those quotes at the beginning and end are part of your cookie json string from what I've seen here.

If that's the case, this should work (trimming away the quote at the beginning and end first).

```
$cookie_string = stripslashes($_COOKIE[$cart_cookie]);
$cookie_string = trim($cookie_string, '"');

$json_data = json_decode($cookie_string);
foreach ($json_data as $item) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have an invalid JSON string. I took the output from `echo $_COOKIE['cookie_cart']` and placed it into [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/), and it does not parse correctly.

You might need to [strip out the slashes first](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php):

```
 $json_data = json_decode(($_COOKIE[$cart_cookie]));
 $products = json_decode($json_data) // confirmed that it's an array
```

The slashes are probably added because you have [magic quotes turn on](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php). It is highly suggested that you turn it off, and take of escaping strings when required yourself.

Comment: `$json_data = json_decode(stripslashes($_COOKIE[$cart_cookie]));` . `$json_data` prints nothing

Comment: Try doing a sanity test first: take the ouput from echo $_COOKIE[$cart_cookie], stripslashes it, and then json_decode it. I took your output string and stripslashes it, and it worked.

Comment: And also are you sure you meant $_COOKIE[$cart_cookie], and not $_COOKIE['cart_cookie] ?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, you could see in my comment. I have simply pasted it here.

Comment: `$json_data = stripslashes($_COOKIE[$cart_cookie]);
            echo $json_data;
            $product = json_decode($json_data);
            echo $product;
             foreach ($product as $key=>$value){}` 
And still getting same warning.

Comment: So when you echo $json_data, what did you get?

Comment: `echo $json_data; \\"[{"id":1353,"product":"prod23","quantity":1,"price":43},{"id":133453,"product":"prod","quantity":1,"price":23}]"` and `echo $product;` prints nothing.